GCP Spring boot error with pubsub "java.io.IOException: Your default credentials were not found
I just recently updated my project from Spring 2 -> 3 and since then I have had issues connecting to pubsub. In the logs I see an error that reads
"java.io.IOException: Your default credentials were not found. To set up Application Default Credentials for your environment

I can get get rid of the error by setting
ENV GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS "/app/test.json"
COPY test.json /app/test.json

In the docker file but of course once I deploy it, it no longer works.
  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.1</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
     </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement> 

then
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-starter-pubsub</artifactId>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <artifactId>threetenbp</artifactId>
      <groupId>org.threeten</groupId>
    </exclusion>
    <exclusion>
      <artifactId>re2j</artifactId>
      <groupId>com.google.re2j</groupId>
    </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
</dependency>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-integration-core</artifactId>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
    <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
    <type>pom</type>
    <scope>import</scope>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-dependencies</artifactId>
    <version>${spring-cloud-gcp.version}</version>
    <type>pom</type>
    <scope>import</scope>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
    <!-- Import dependency management from Spring Boot -->
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
    <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
    <type>pom</type>
    <scope>import</scope>
  </dependency>

<spring-boot.version>3.2.5</spring-boot.version>
<spring-cloud-gcp.version>3.7.7</spring-cloud-gcp.version>
<spring-cloud.version>2022.0.5</spring-cloud.version>

in my application-local.propertiesfile I add
spring.cloud.gcp.pubsub.emulator-host=localhost:8681
spring.cloud.gcp.project-id=local-project

and in the main application.properties file
#pubsub
spring.cloud.gcp.project-id=${PP_VARS_PROJECTID:pp-playground}
Reading the docs there isn't much difference between the spring 2 -> 3 implementation. My versions also seem to be compatible
I also should not need a service account within my dockerfile. GCP Spring integration should be handling this for me.
Has anyone had this issue when upgrading to Spring 3?
